# Different CSV files based on value

Tags: c#, csv, file-io

I'm having a question about my CSV.
I export a CSV and read it in C#. 
The last colomn of each line in CSV is A,B,C,D,E or G.
Now, I want my CSV to be cut in pieces, like; I want a new CSV with the lines which contain A and D. And another one which contains B and C for example.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm stuck..

This is a part of my code

```
StreamReader debtors = new StreamReader(@"C:\CSV\Debtors.csv");
StreamWriter debtorsMetaal = new StreamWriter(@"C:\CSV\DebtorsMetaal.csv");
StreamWriter debtorsSystemen = new StreamWriter(@"C:\CSV\DebtorsSystemen.csv");
StreamWriter debtorsHolding = new StreamWriter(@"C:\CSV\DebtorsHolding.csv");

while(debtors.Peek() >=0)
{
   string line = debtors.ReadLine();
   try
   {
     string[] rowsArray = line.Split(';');

    //..... etc
```

Now the lines are in pieces, but how can I select the last colomn in my line and create a new CSV file based upon the values of the last colomn?

debtorsMetaal, debtorsSystemen and debtorsHolding will be the new CSV files.

For example;

In a line in the CSV I have the following info

```
number - name- description - type
```

Where type can be A, B, C, D , E or G.
Now I want the lines where type = A and the lines where type = D together in one CSV file.
Is this even possible?

The values A,B,C,D,E or G are always in colomn AJ in excel format.

Comment: are you missing the rest of your while block?  why can't you read them into a List<string[]> and then check the last column to see which file to write them to?

Comment: Reading a CSV file is not as easy as you think. I suggest you have a look at this library: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Comment: I added some more info

Comment: Good point @Harrison , I can check it by if List<string[3]> == A or something?

Comment: can you put some data as example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a loop like this:

```
var adLines = new List<string>();
var bcLines = new List<string>();
var unknownLines = new List<string>();
var adList = new[]{"A", "D"};
var bcList = new[]{"B", "C"};
using(var debtors = new StreamReader(@"C:\CSV\Debtors.csv"))
{
    string line = null;
    while((line = debtors.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] columns = line.Split(';'); // you should check if columns.Length is correct
        string lastColumn = columns.Last().Trim();
        if(adList.Contains(lastColumn, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            adLines.Add(line);
        else if(bcList.Contains(lastColumn, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            bcLines.Add(line);
        else
            unknownLines.Add(line);
    }
}
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\CSV\DebtorsSystemen.csv", adLines);
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\CSV\DebtorsHolding.csv", bcLines);
```

However, in general you should not reinvent the wheel and use an abvailable CSV-parser like:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Comment: Did I ever tell you you were the best?! I owe you a beer! :D

Comment: Careful, i might take you up on that, it's a short distance ;)

Comment: Haha I noticed, neighbour! ;)